# Angular 5 and PHP can't use the POST method to send a value to server scripts

Tags: php, angular, post, httpclient, angular5

I am having a problem using post method in Angular 5 and PHP.

I have this method from a `.ts` class:

```
addPartners(partnerName)
{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    this.name = JSON.stringify(partnerName)
    console.log("hi "+ this.name)
    return this.http.post('http://aff.local/addPartner.php', this.name, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'json'
    }).pipe(map(
    res=>{
      console.log(res)
    }
  ))
}
```

And I will call it on `(click)` event of a button:

```
addPartner(){
    this.email = this.subscribeForm.get('emailTxt').value;
    //console.log(this.email)
    this.api.addPartners(this.email).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.subscribeForm.reset();
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      }
      );
}
```

The PHP script is :

addPartner($partnerName);
    echo $result;
?>

When I fill the textbox and click on the button, the value sent is empty.

When I change the method, by sending the variable in the `url` it work properly.

Here is the working script. In the api main class:

```
addPartners(partnerName)
  {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    this.name = JSON.stringify(partnerName)
    console.log("hi "+ name)
    return this.http.post('http://aff.local/addPartner.php?name='+ name, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'json'
    }).pipe(map(
        res=>{
          console.log(res)
        }
      ))
  }
```

I just changed the url into:

```
http://aff.local/addPartner.php?name='+ name,
```

And in the php script I will get it using `$_REQUEST['name']`.

What I want is using the `POST` method because I need to send multiple data from a form.

Comment: There is your problem ? Multiple parameters can be send like this https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters . Or does it fal in your php script ? If yes please add it.

Comment: remove ?name=name from the url and add it as post param  .. 
?name=name is regular GET param and it's not send as POST

Comment: I don't want to send a variable through URL. I need to send multiple variables using POST method

Comment: On http.post 2nd param after url is the array with DATA to be posted .. 
Whatever you want to receive at the PHP file as POST data must be attached there. .

Comment: I can see the data at the console. So there is no problem from angular side.

Comment: At PHP there is $_POST['name'] for post and $_GET['name'] for get params
When you use $_REQUEST['name'] it returns by default GET param if is set, else POST if is set .. (this depends on how is configured the server)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use JSON.stringify so you can take params from the server side using :

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body);
```

or if we want to just take data using $_POST['paramName'] so we have to use the below in your client side:

```
let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
let data = {name: partnerName};
let body = this.formatData(test);
```

and format your data like that:

```
formatData(data) {
    let returnData = '';
    let count = 0;
    for (let i in data) {
      if (count == 0) {
        returnData += i + '=' + data[i];
      } else {
        returnData += '&' + i + '=' + data[i];
      }
      count = count + 1;
    }
    return returnData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the POST-example you used `this.name`, but in the GET-example only `name`.

Try to use [`$_POST['name']`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php) instead of [`$_REQUEST['name]`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php), because [`$_REQUEST['name]` is a different variable](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php#84527) then [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php) or [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) and also differently treated.