# ErrorException: 'Trying to get property of non-object' while sending a POST request from Angular 5 Service to Laravel 5.4 API

Tags: angular, laravel-5.4

I am trying to access data from a Laravel API for my Angular front-end.
To receive the required data, I have to send an 'id' as POST to the url which in turn queries the database and returns the result as JSON.
USING POSTMAN and other API tester tools, I have verified that the endpoint is working correctly.
WHEN I try to send the POST request from Angular, I do not receive the POST data on my Laravel API and the following error is given.

Please note that I have removed the actual URLs from the code

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

in ServiceRequestController.php line 209
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/removed_name/public_html/KoiKaam/app/Http/Controllers/ServiceRequestController.php', 209, array('request' => object(Request), 'serviceRequests' => object(Collection), 'id' => null, 'category' => null, 'cats' => object(Collection), 'cat' => null))
in ServiceRequestController.php line 209
```

While the actual result as tested on POSTMAN and from an Android Application should be [this (a screenshot of the result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFMND.png)

This is the code of the angular service I am using to fetch the results

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BuyDeliverRequests } from '../classes/buy-deliver-requests';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
const httpPostOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};

@Injectable()
export class BuyDeliverRequestsService {
    private url = 'http://removed_name/KoiKaam/public/api/serviceRequestByCategory'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getBuyDeliverServices(serverResponse: BuyDeliverRequests) {

      return this.http.post(this.url, {id: 1},  httpPostOptions).subscribe(
        data => { serverResponse = data.data; console.log(data); },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Successful')
      );
  }
}
```

This is the function that the URL/endpoint goes to, to fetch the results:

```
 /*this function returns all rows of service request wrt category with their picture paths from service request pictures table
    and bids on that request request*/
    public function showServiceRequestbyCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $serviceRequests = new Collection();
        $id = $request->id; 

        $category = Category::find($id);
        $this->categories->push($category);
        $cats = $this->getChilds($id);
        try{
            foreach ($cats as $cat){
                $srv = $this->getServiceRequest($cat->id); //This is line 209 from the error
                foreach ($srv as $service){
                    $serviceRequests->push($service);
                }
            }

            $response["message"] = "Post Created Successfully";
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["data"] = $serviceRequests;
            return json_encode($response);
        }
        catch (QueryException $e){
            $response["message"] = $e->errorInfo[2];
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["sja"] = "2nd";
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

Following is the function that is being called on the line where error is identified by Laravel

```
private function getServiceRequest($category_id){
    try{
        $serviceRequest = ServiceRequest::where([['category_id','=', $category_id],
            ['in_process_flag', '=', false]])->paginate(5);
        if($serviceRequest){
            return $serviceRequest;
        }
    }
    catch(QueryException $e){

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your mysql fetch statement from php?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal I have edited the question to add the code for Database Interaction. I am using Eloquent for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, finally pointed out the problem and found a solution

### Problem

When Angular 5 sends the data via POST, it sends it as JSON. My controller on the Laravel End is expecting as a FORM Data which can be accessed as `$request->id`

### Solution

There are two ways in which this can be resolved. On the Angular side or the Laravel side.

**Laravel**

It's simple really, instead of directly accessing the `$request` we first need to store it in an array

```
$data= $request->json()->all();
```

then we can use the `$data` as an associative array to fetch the required data e.g. if I wanted to use **id**, I would

`$id= $data['id'];` then use $id as necessary

**Angular**

We first need to serialize our object in which data is stored before POSTING it to Laravel backend. jQuery had its own function `$.param()` for that but since we're using angular, I found a custom function which does the same thing

```
formatData(data) {
let returnData = '';
let count = 0;
for (let i in data) {
  if (count == 0) {
    returnData += i + '=' + data[i];
  } else {
    returnData += '&' + i + '=' + data[i];
  }
  count = count + 1;
}
return returnData;
}
```

so for sending data I had to edit the Service class fucntion as follows

```
getServicesByCategory(category_id: number) {
let data = {id: category_id};
let body = this.formatData(data);
  return this.http.post(this.url, body,  httpPostOptions);
}
```

found this function on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384607/4622670)